# Location and how to recover cache from Google Chrome from an Android phone?

Tags: data-recovery, htc-one-s

I'm wondering if it's possible to recover files from the Google Chrome cache from an Android phone, specifically, an HTC One S running Android 4.0.2.

I'm trying to recover the stylesheet from a site whose data has been partially lost, and of course this phone is the only device to have accessed it today before the crash.

Comment: Hi! I've made the question more generalized and removed the edit since it was an answer which doesn't belong in the question. Please post it as an answer. If you don't want to then let me know. I'll add a wiki answer then. Readers: [here is the answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/41033/2) which was edited in the question earlier.